# Use for loop and .loc to create a new column and add value equals to lenght of first column data

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to pandas, So i am trying to create a new column and add the value of column as total lenght of names of first column. But it is giving all column value same which is equal to the value of lenght of last item of first column.

```html
import pandas as pd

mydictionary = {'names': ['Somuli', 'Kiu', 'mol', 'Lixxxx'],
    'physics': [68, 74, 77, 78],
    'chemistry': [84, 56, 73, 69],
    'algebra': [78, 88, 82, 87]}

# Create dataframe
df_marks = pd.DataFrame(mydictionary)
print('Original DataFrame\n--------------')
print(df_marks)

# Add column
df_marks['geometry'] = ""

print('\n\n DataFrame after adding "geometry" column\n--------------')

mynames = df_marks['names'].unique()

for std in mynames :
  df_marks['geometry']=len(std)
   
print(df_marks)
```

Answer (score 2):

This would get you the length of each row in the names column
`df_marks['geometry'] = df_marks['names'].str.len()`

Here is the link to the Series str.len method:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html

Output

|  | names | physics | chemistry | algebra | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Somuli | 68 | 84 | 78 | 6 |
| 1 | Kiu | 74 | 56 | 88 | 3 |
| 2 | mol | 77 | 73 | 82 | 3 |
| 3 | Lixxxx | 78 | 69 | 87 | 6 |

---

You can also do this with the .loc method using (but `str.len()` is more efficient):

```
for idx in df_marks.index:
    df_marks.loc[idx, 'geometry'] = len(df_marks.loc[idx, 'names'])
```

Here is documentation for the .loc method:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html

---

@ProAcademy if you really wanted to adapt your existing for loop you could use:

```
for std in mynames:
    df_marks.loc[df_marks['names'] == std, 'geometry'] = len(std)
```

This would loop over each unique name, filter for the rows that have this name and assign the geometry column to the length of `std`.
On the other hand, using `df_marks['geometry']=len(std)` in the for loop reassigns all the rows of all unique names to the length of the current value of `std` in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks @renzo21. Can we use .loc to achive what i want?

Comment: But still How can i use my own code and what should i do inside my for loop i have used instead of df_marks['geometry']=len(std)  ? I used df_marks.loc['geometry']=len(std) but that also dosen't work.

Comment: @ProAcademy, You don't need `for` loop + `.loc` when you have a vectorized operation